# How to manage water pooling at a particular spot in my lawn?

Tags: water, drainage, lawn

Per the picture, I have an interesting draining issue where some rain water will drain along my roof's edge to a spot on my lawn. Problem is that the water is pooling in heavier rains (see picture below)

Are there recommended ways to handle water pooling due to draining water?

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't be so quick to cut the down spout, that may ultimately be needed, but I think you need to study the situation while it's raining first.   It appears the gutter is not performing as intended and water is running off.  Is that because the downspout is getting backed up then maybe cut it off but maybe it's just clogged.  Once you get the drainage problem identified and fixed then add dirt to get rid of the indentation, positive slope away from the house. Then cover with sod.

Answer (score 3):

Cut the down spout off about a foot and one half.  Then fix a 45° bend to the bottom of the downspout.  Now install a 3-4' section onto that elbow and extend it out onto the lawn.  The rain water should now dissipate into the lawn before it can find its way back to that low spot. When mowing, set the extension to the side.

Answer (score 1):

From your picture being this side of the gutter it is hard to tell if the roof edge you are referring to extends out away from the gutter system but that is what I am thinking you are trying to show and if that is the case - there is a simple solution to this problem - some people who do not have gutters use a guide flashing (diverter) to cause the water to run away from the entry ways. So here is my suggestion:

Place a rain diverter on your roof to cause the water that runs down the edge of it to run into the gutter that you have.

[How to Install a Rain Water Diverter](https://www.thisoldhouse.com/how-to/how-to-install-rain-diverter)

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure, but that downspout is definitely not doing what it is intended to do, which is move water away from your house. it would be a good idea to dig a trench leading away from your house with a slight downward slope and attach run a corrugated pipe from the bottom of your downspout into that trench, and then cover it back up. This might actually help your problem... but as far as the water actually dripping off the corner of your roof, not so sure what to do about that.